# How to delete elements from list1 appearing in list2?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to functional programming of Mathematica and trying to remove one list of assorted elements from another. However I only find functions working with the Index rather than the values itself:

```
 list1={b,a,e,f,c,d}  
 list2={f,e,c}
```

I can now remove `list2` from `list1`:

```
 result={b,a,d}
```

I already found out, that you can "abuse"

```
DeleteCases[list1, a]
```

to remove 1 specific element from a list, but not a whole assorted list...

I would be very grateful for a simple solution to do it.
Thanks a lot for any answer!

Comment: Not functional, but just for fun: `list1 /. Thread[list2 -> Nothing]`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use

```
DeleteCases[list1, Alternatives @@ list2]
```

In new versions (M8.0+), `DeleteCases` is optimized on patterns not involving blanks, so this will be fast also for large lists. For earlier versions, this will work:

```
Replace[list1, Dispatch[Thread[list2 -> Sequence[]]],{1}]
```

being 2-3 times slower, but still very fast.

Comment: thank you a lot, I do have V.8 and it works perfectly! Thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: Thanks for including version-specific information; if you had not I would be left guessing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for any nested list! :) Great solution!

Comment: @AnastasiiaAnishchenko No problem :-). Actually, it only works on level 1. You probably meant that elements can be anything, including being themselves lists. Actually, I have developed a more general set of routines for similar kinds of operations, see the *UnsortedOperations* package on [this page](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/additional_resources.html)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I am curious about the principle of `DeleteCases`. Why is it so fast than `Select[list1, FreeQ[list2, #] &]`? And I don't know the principle of `Dispatch` either. May be they have the same principle?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and I found that though `Complement` sort result, but it's even faster then `DeleteCases` when I test large list!

Comment: @matheorem These are not the questions to be answered in comments, and also I have zero time now. Search the site, the answers are there.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This is great.  How can I read the docs to imply that `DeleteCases` is guaranteed not to reorder (aside from possible flattening)?  Is this guarantee explicit?

Comment: @Alan If you mean reodering the remaining entries in the first list, then I think `DeleteCases` does guarantee that this will not happen. Not sure how well that is expressed in the docs though.

Answer (score 30):

You are perhaps searching for `Complement`. `Complement[list1, list2]` results in `{a, b, d}`. The result is sorted though. If you are looking for an unsorted complement, `DeleteCases[list1, Alternatives @@ list2]` should probably work. I think there are some discussions on unsorted complements out there at google.

Comment: Uh, Leonid beat me here. Should I leave the answer here anyway?

Comment: Keep it, why not? I did not mention `Complement` (I actually implicitly assumed that the resulting list should not be sorted, which may or may not be the case).

Comment: yes this is true. I found `Complement` on google, but I need the result to be unsorted.

Comment: @PeriodicProgrammer Next time, please remember to include what you've tried and your constraints (unsorted), so that people don't waste time suggesting that.

Answer (score 21):

Iff each list is internally free of duplicates you can use this very quick method:

```
DeleteDuplicates[#2 ~Join~ #] ~Drop~ Length[#2] &[list1, list2]
```

Comment: Clever trick. +1.

Comment: This will keep list 1 in its original order—just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 18):

Since Yves beat me narrowly to my first solution, here's another one using `Select`:

```
Select[list1, FreeQ[list2, #] &]
Out[2]= {b, a, d}
```

This does not sort your result.

---

You can also use `Complement`, which is more intuitive. Example:

```
Complement[list1, list2]
Out[1]= {a, b, d}
```

Note that this sorts your result (i.e., it is not in the same order, `{b, a, d}`).

Answer (score 13):

Unsorted `Complement`. I think it originates from MathGroup. It accepts the `SameTest` option.

```
Options[UnsortedComplement] = {SameTest -> Automatic};
UnsortedComplement[all_, del___, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Replace[all, 
   List @@ (Rule[#, Sequence[]] & /@ Union[del, opts]), {1}];

all = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {20}]
UnsortedComplement[all, {6, 2, 8}, {2, 3, 4}]

(*
  ==> {8, 4, 2, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 8, 0, 5, 5, 8, 1}

  ==> {5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 1}
*)
```

It also works with any head, not just `List`-s.

Answer (score 7):

Just nest it:

```
Fold[DeleteCases[#1, #2] &, list1, list2]
```

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate to add to this old discussion after these excellent answers and other essential reading especially [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/Book.html), but this amalgamation of many suggestions may be of interest.
cutEverything[xx_, removeList__] removes all entries of all elements of removeList_ from xx_ regardless of their depth or whether they are duplicates. It leaves compounds in place and does not change the original list order.

```
x = 
  {pudepied, pudepied.txt, {pudepied}, {{{pudepied}}, {zap}, {{peter}}}, {{pudepied}}, 
   blah, zap, "Wolfram Language", {peter}, {{{}}}, mary, {{{{mary}}}}};

remove = {pudepied, peter, mary, {}};
cutEverything[xx_, removeList_] := 
  Replace[xx, x_List :> DeleteCases[x, Alternatives @@ removeList], {0, Infinity}]
cutEverything[x, remove]
```

> ```
>  {pudepied.txt, {{zap}}, blah, zap, Wolfram Language}
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

```
DeleteElements[{b, a, e, f, c, d}, \[Infinity] \[Rule] {f, e, c}]

    (*{b, a, d}*)
```

Unfortunately, the *new* function `DeleteElements` is not faster:

```
In[1]:= list1 = RandomReal[1, 2*^4]; list2 = 
         Catenate[{RandomChoice[list1, 6*^3], RandomReal[1, 4*^3]}];

In[2]:= result0=DeleteElements[list1,list2];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[2]= {3.78426, Null}

In[3]:= result1=DeleteCases[list1,Alternatives@@list2];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[3]= {0.01786, Null}

In[4]:= result2=Replace[list1,Dispatch[Thread[list2->Sequence[]]],{1}];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[4]= {0.0342811, Null}

In[5]:= result3=Replace[list1,x_List:>DeleteCases[x,Alternatives@@list2],{0,Infinity}];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[5]= {0.0222806, Null}

In[6]:= result4=Fold[DeleteCases[##]&,list1,list2];//AbsoluteTiming

Out[6]= {24.3309, Null}

In[7]:= Equal[result0,result1,result2,result3,result4]

Out[7]= True
```

Other ways are much slower, so I omit them here.

Answer (score 3):

To explore the preceding answer a little bit further:

```
list1 = {b, a, e, f, c, d};
list2 = {f, e, c};

DeleteElements[list1, list2]
```

{b, a, d}

If list1 contains duplicated elements:

```
list1 = {b, a, e, f, c, c, d};
list2 = {f, e, c};
```

Delete all elements:

```
DeleteElements[list1, list2]
```

{b, a, d}

Delete up to 1 element:

```
DeleteElements[list1, 1 -> list2]
```

{b, a, c, d}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases`:

```
list1 = {b, a, e, f, c, d};
list2 = {f, e, c};

Cases[list1, x_ /; FreeQ[x, Alternatives @@ list2] :> x]

{b, a, d}
```

Comment: Similar: `Pick[list1, FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ list2] & /@ list1]`

Comment: It's a very good solution, @eldo! Thanks for pointing it out. :-)