# How do I obtain an intersection of two or more list of lists conditioned on the first element of each sub-list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given two lists like

```
list1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}};
list2 = {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}};
```

I would like to produce an output like

```
listout = {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question.  Second try.

[`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) & [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html):

```
f1[a_List, b_List] := 
   Reap[Sow[#2, #] & @@@ a ~Join~ b, a[[All, 1]] ⋂ b[[All, 1]], List][[2, All, 1]]
```

[`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html):

```
f2[a_List, b_List] :=
 With[{aa = a[[All, 1]], bb = b[[All, 1]]},
   {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@
      Pick[a ~Join~ b, aa ~Join~ bb, Alternatives @@ (aa ⋂ bb)] ~GatherBy~ First
 ]
```

*Edit:* Here is another method using [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GatherBy.html).  While this method did not come to mind when I first wrote this answer I have used related methods for some time.  It works by preconditioning `GatherBy` so that we collect the expressions we want at the beginning of the results and then discarding the rest.  This is the same principle I used for [How to Delete Elements from List1 appearing in List2?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/how-to-delete-elements-from-list1-appearing-in-list2/1295#1295) and more recently [Complement on pre-sorted lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30429/complement-on-pre-sorted-lists/30434#30434), and which jVincent used for [Counting the population of integers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19357/counting-the-population-of-integers/19386#19386).

```
f3[a_List, b_List] := 
  With[{pre = List /@ ( a[[All, 1]] ⋂ b[[All, 1]] )},
    {pre[[All, 1]], GatherBy[Join[pre, a, b], First][[;; Length@pre, 2 ;;, 2]]}\[Transpose]
  ]
```

At the expense of greater code length this can be made faster by using Szabolcs's [inversion method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/121) with `GatherBy`:

```
f4[a_List, b_List] :=
 Module[{pre, first, all, n, a1, b1},
   {a1, b1} = {a[[All, 1]], b[[All, 1]]};
   n = Length[pre = a1 ⋂ b1];
   first = Join[pre, a1, b1];
   all = Join[a, b];
   {pre, Map[all[[#, 2]] &, 
      GatherBy[Range@Length@first, first[[#]] &][[;; n, 2 ;;]] - n]}\[Transpose]
 ]
```

Test:

```
list1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}};
list2 = {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}, {5, 7}};

f1[list1, list2]
```

> ```
> {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}}
> ```

I included `{5, 7}` in `list2` to show that this is finding the intersection of the two lists and not merely repeats within a single list.

Comment: For those of us who cannot read infix: `f2[a_, b_] := ({#1[[1, 1]], #1[[All, 2]]} & ) /@ 
     GatherBy[
   Cases[Join[a, 
     b], {Alternatives @@ 
      Intersection[a[[All, 1]], b[[All, 1]]], _}], First]`

Comment: Looks fine to me. Would be interested to know how `Apply` `Alternative` compares with the `MemberQ` test for larger lists. I normally use `Alternative` but forgot all about it when I wrote my answer

Comment: @Mike `Alternatives` test quite a bit faster than `MemberQ` for me.  For pure speed this seems best of what I've tried: `Pick[#, First /@ #, Alternatives @@ inter] & @ Join[a, b]` where `inter` is the first elements intersection.

Comment: Yes `Pick` will generally provide a much faster solution than e.g. `Cases`/`Select` if you can develop a `Pick` method.

Answer (score 13):

this works for the given example:

```
ReplaceList[{list1, list2}, {{___, {a_, b_}, ___}, {___, {a_, c_}, ___}} :> {a, {b, c}}]

(* {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}} *)
```

Comment: Very clever!  However, this runs into problems if there are duplicates (in terms of first element) internally in either list.  It is also rather slow on longer lists.  Enthusiastic +1 nevertheless!

Comment: An additional note: make sure you use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) when working with named patterns on the right-hand side.  This correctly localizes the symbols.  I made this edit for you; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for your vote, your editing, and many of your wonderful answers I learn and love :)

Answer (score 10):

Update 3: A generalization for any number of lists and any column as the key:

```
 ClearAll[combineBy];
 combineBy[lists : __List, col_Integer] /; (col <= Min[Length /@ # & /@ {lists}]) := 
  With[{intNodes =  Alternatives @@ Intersection @@ (#[[col]] & /@ # & /@ {lists}),
  joined = GatherBy[Join[lists], #[[col]] &],
  othercols = DeleteCases[Range[Min[Length /@ # & /@ {lists}]], col]},
  {#[[1, col]], Join @@ #[[All, othercols]]} & /@
     Pick[joined, ! FreeQ[#[[1, col]], intNodes] & /@ joined]]
```

OP's example:

```
  list1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}};
  list2 = {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}, {5, 7}};
  combineBy[list1, list2, 1]
  (* {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}} *)
  combineBy[list1, list2, 2]
  (* {{9, {3, 3}}} *)
```

More examples:

```
  list3 = Table[RandomSample[Range[7], 3], {3}];
  list4 = Table[RandomSample[Range[7], 3], {4}];
  list5 = Table[RandomSample[Range[7], 3], {6}];

  Prepend[Prepend[{SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove,  #, 
   Column[combineBy[list4, list5, #]]} & /@ {2, 3},
   {Column@list4, Column@list5, 1, Column[combineBy[list4, list5, 1]]}],
   {"list4", "list5", "key column", "result"}] //
   Grid[#, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

```
  Prepend[Prepend[{SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, #, 
   Column[combineBy[list3, list4, #]]} & /@ {2, 3},
   {Column@list3, Column@list4, 1, Column[combineBy[list3, list4, 1]]}],
   {"list3", "list4", "key column", "result"}] //
   Grid[#, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

```
  Prepend[Prepend[{SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove,  #, 
   Column[combineBy[list3, list5, #]]} & /@ {2, 3},
   {Column@list3, Column@list5, 1,  Column[combineBy[list3, list5, 1]]}],
   {"list3", "list5", "key column", "result"}] //
   Grid[#, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

```
  Prepend[Prepend[{SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove,  #, 
     Column[combineBy[list3, list4, list5, #]]} & /@ {2, 3},
    {Column@list3, Column@list4, Column@list5, 1,
      Column[combineBy[list3, list4, list5, 1]]}],
    {"list3", "list4", "list5", "key column", "result"}] //
   Grid[#, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

---

```
  ClearAll[combine];
  combine[list1_List, list2_List] := 
  With[{intNodes = Intersection[First /@ list1, First /@ list2], 
    joined =  GatherBy[Join[list1, list2], First]},
    {First[First@#],  Last[#]} & /@ (Transpose /@ 
    Select[joined, MemberQ[intNodes, #[[1, 1]]] &])]

 combine[list1, list2]
 (* {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}} *)
 combine[list1, {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}, {5, 7}}]
 (* {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}} *)
```

(Updated with correction thanks to @Mr.W's comment: the second argument of `Select` is changed from `Length[#]>2&` in the original post to the correct version that accounts for the intersection of the first columns of the two lists.)

Update 2: Using `Pick` instead of `Select`:

```
ClearAll[combine2];
combine2[list1_List, list2_List] := 
 With[{intNodes = Intersection[First /@ list1, First /@ list2], 
   joined =  GatherBy[Join[list1, list2], First]}, 
 {#[[1, 1]], #[[-1]]} & /@ 
  (Transpose /@ Pick[joined, MemberQ[intNodes, #[[1, 1]]] & /@ joined])]
```

Comment: @Mr.W thank you ... updated with correction.

Comment: Gladly up-voted.

Comment: Funny, I was just trying `Pick` myself.  See the comments below my answer.  Great minds and all that.

Comment: @Mr.W, of the triplets (`Cases`, `Select`,`Pick`), `Pick` is almost always the first that I try ... and  it rarely disappoints.

Answer (score 7):

I like this one:

```
{#[[1,1]],#[[All,2]]}&/@Select[GatherBy[list1~Join~list2,First],Length[#]>1&]

(*{{2,{4,6}},{3,{9,9}},{4,{16,12}}}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 1**

```
processList[list1_, list2_] := Module[{intersection, tmp1, tmp2},

 (* find the intersection of the all the first elements *)
  intersection = Intersection[list1[[All, 1]], list2[[All, 1]]];

 (* now find cases in each list in which the first element is one of the intersecting   
  elements *)
  tmp1 = Cases[list1, {x_ /; MemberQ[intersection, x], __}];
  tmp2 = Cases[list2, {x_ /; MemberQ[intersection, x], __}];

  (* now gather all sub-lists based on the first element and map them to give the   
  desired output *)
  {#[[1, 1]], ##[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[Join[tmp1, tmp2], First]
  ]
```

test:

```
processList[list1, {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}, {5, 7}}]
(* {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}} *)
```

**Edit 2**

Since we're onto `Pick` methods :) ...this seems relatively concise. Two steps from above and then pick out the elements for output.

```
processList2[list1_, list2_] := Module[{intersection, tmp},

  intersection = Intersection[list1[[All, 1]], list2[[All, 1]]];
  tmp = {#[[1, 1]], ##[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[Join[list1, list2], First];
  Pick[tmp, tmp[[All, 1]] /. Thread[Rule[intersection, True]]]
  ]

list2 = {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}, {5, 7}};
processList2[list1, list2]
(* {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}}  *)
```

For all of these `Pick` methods I'm not sure how efficient creating the stencil can be for this particular problem. If the stencil is efficiently created then `Pick` is a fast way of picking out elements from lists.

Comment: How does this find an *intersection* of the two lists?

Comment: Re: Edit, that looks like a more intelligent approach than the one I just posted.  I hope you don't mind if I borrow from it. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard not sure how intelligent it is, or efficient. Just a stepwise approach. :)

Comment: Please take a look at my answer now and tell me if you see anything wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I should insist on your removing infix notation before looking at it :)

Answer (score 5):

```
a = Join[list1, list2]
n = Length[list1];
{a[[#, 1]], {a[[#, 2]], a[[# + n - 1, 2]]}} & /@ Range[2, n]

![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXKvd.png)
```

Explanation: Use linear indexing. We have 2 matrices as input. `list1` and `list2`. Each is an `n by 2` size matrix. Joining them results in one `2n by 2` matrix called `a`. This diagram explains the algorithm 
[image]

Comment: Am I correct in observing that this only works if the two lists have a common _ordered_ subset, _e.g._ `{2, 3, 4}`?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a rule-based approach:

```
list2/.{{i_Integer/;!MemberQ[list1[[All,1]],i],x_}:>Sequence[],{i_Integer,x_}:>{i,{i/.(Rule@@@list1),x}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Association` - related functions (not yet available in 2012)

```
a = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}};
b = {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}};

Cases[{_, {_, __}}] @
 KeyValueMap[List] @ Merge[# &] @ MapApply[Rule] @ Join[a, b]
```

{{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}}

Answer (score 2):

#### [GroupBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)

```
WolframLanguageData["GroupBy",
  {"VersionIntroduced",  "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

```
a = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}};
b = {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15}};

MapApply[List] @
Normal @ 
Select[Length @ # > 1 &] @ 
GroupBy[Join[a, b], First -> Last]
```

> ```
> {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}}
> ```

```
Map[{#[[1, 1]], Flatten @ #[[All, 2 ;;]]} &] @
Values @ 
Select[Length@# > 1 &] @ 
GroupBy[Join[a, b], First]
```

> ```
> {{2, {4, 6}}, {3, {9, 9}}, {4, {16, 12}}}
> ```

```
WolframLanguageData["WolframLanguageData", 
  {"VersionIntroduced",  "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Cases[KeyValueMap[List]@GroupBy[Join[list1,list2],First->Last],{a_,{b_,c__}}->{a,{b,c}}]

(* {{2,{4,6}},{3,{9,9}},{4,{16,12}}} *)
```

```
list1x = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}};
list2x = {{2, 6}, {3, 9}, {4, 12}, {5, 15},{2,100},{2,2},{2,1}};

Cases[KeyValueMap[List]@GroupBy[Join[list1x,list2x],First->Last],{a_,{b_,c__}}->{a,{b,c}}]

(* {{2,{4,6,100,2,1}},{3,{9,9}},{4,{16,12}}} *)
```