# Partitioning a list and gathering statistics on the distribution of values across partitions

Tags: vector, version-5

I have a one-dimensional array of 200 elements consisting of the numbers 0, 1, 2. This array needs to be divided into 10 groups (20 items each). Then, for each group, I want to count how many of the elements 0, 1, 2 is in each of them. These findings should be stored in three arrays, `n0, n1, n2`: `n0` containing the statistics for the zeros, `n1` the statistics for the ones, `n2` the statistics for the threes.

For example, one might get `n0 = {3, 4, 3, 6, 8, 12, 1, 9, 15, 16, ...}`, so in the first 20 elements of the original array there were 3 zeros, in the following 20 there were 4 zeros, and so on.

I have *Mathematica* 5.0. Please keep in mind that functions first appearing in later versions are not available to me.

Comment: Unfortunately `Tally` is new in V6 but `Partition`/`Count`/`Sow`/`Reap` are available to you. Could you please provide a minimal example, e.g. 20 elements divided on 4 groups and a desired output. Now it is unclear what do you want to after counting them.

Comment: I have a table {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}.Divide in 4 groups (this groups I don't show during the program) {2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0} In groups I count elements 0,1,2 and write them into vectors: n0={4,3,2,4}(number of 0 in each group), n1={0,1,2,1}(number of 1 in each group), n2={1,1,1,0}(number of 2 in each group).This vectors (n0,n1,n2) I must see in the program after. Next step: this vectors I have put in one matrix where the row are this vectors.

Comment: Your previous question was closed as a duplicate and indeed, methods there need `Tally` which you can't use. But the [first answer there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19373/5478) does not use it so you can adapt it, can't you?

Answer (score 5):

All you need are [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) and [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Count.html). Both were available in V1.1. Lets take it step by step.

First some random data. For demonstration purposes 20 elements will be enough.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, 20]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2}
> ```

Again for demonstration purposes, 5 groups of 4 elements each will suffice.

```
groups = Partition[data, 4]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 1, 2}}
> ```

Now map a function that counts the zeros in each group across the list of groups.

```
 n0 = Count[#, 0] & /@ groups
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 3, 4, 0}
> ```

Similarly for the ones and twos.

```
n1 = Count[#, 1] & /@ groups
n2 = Count[#, 2] & /@ groups
```

> ```
> {2, 0, 0, 0, 1}
> {1, 1, 1, 0, 3}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> *I have Mathematica 5.0....*

So the following may be of interest for users with versions 10+:

```
ClearAll[countsByGroups]
countsByGroups = Transpose[{0, 1, 2} /. Normal[KeySort /@ Counts /@ Partition[##]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
data = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, 20]
```

> {1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2}

```
Partition[data, 4]
```

> {{1, 2, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 1, 2}}

```
countsByGroups[data, 4]
```

> {{1, 3, 3, 4, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 3}}

```
Partition[data, 5]
```

> {{1, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 2, 1, 2}}

```
countsByGroups[data, 5]
```

> {{2, 3, 5, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 3}}

Comment: ...with the caveat that `Counts[]` and `KeySort[]` (and associations for that matter) were not around in version 5.

Comment: @J.M., just noticed v5:)