# Finding duplicates in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of integer, and I want to know if the list contains any duplicates.
My code is working, but I feel there is a more straightforward way of doing this

```
list1 = Range[10];
list2 = {1,2,3,4,1,6};
DoublesQ[list_] := Count[Tally[list], {_,n_}  /; n >1 ] == 0]

DoublesQ[list1]
=> True

DoublesQ[list2]
=> False
```

EDIT: So appears that Mathematica 10 has a function for that. I guess that now my question is: how can I do that *without* the build-in function?

Comment: `Length@Union@list1==Length@list1` for xample

Comment: In V10 there is `DuplicateFreeQ`.

Comment: @belisarius you should post an answer

Comment: @mete I think this one is a dup. There was a question with some performance figures for different methods, but I can't find it now. Someone will ...

Comment: I read this, but it seemed different from what I wanted: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19357/counting-the-population-of-integers/19386#19386

Comment: [related/possible duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6745/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New in Mathematica 10 is the function [`DuplicateFreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DuplicateFreeQ.html)

```
list1 = Range[10];
list2 = {1,2,3,4,1,6};

DuplicateFreeQ /@ {list1, list2}
(* {True, False} *)
```