# Deleting elements on a list by the first element of another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I was trying to make this

```
L1 = {{2, 1}, {6, 4}, {8, 7}, {9, 5}};
L2 = {{2, 9}, {9, 6}};
L = Union[L2 , L1]
```

And I used this:

```
Cases[L, {{a_, _}, {b_, _}} /; a == b]
Complement[L,L2]
```

And this:

```
DeleteCases[L, MemberQ[L1, {#[[1]], _}] & /@ L2]
```

But, both fail. The answer must take from L1 only the elements where the first element appear in L2. For L1 and L2 above, must return

```
{{2,1},{9,5}}
```

And {6, 4} and {8, 7} must be dropped from L2!

Thanks,

Comment: Closely related: [How do I obtain an intersection of two or more list of lists conditioned on the first element of each sub-list?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16450/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Cases`:

```
L1 = {{2, 1}, {6, 4}, {8, 7}, {9, 5}};
L2 = {{2, 9}, {9, 6}};

With[{a = Alternatives @@ L2[[All, 1]]}, Cases[L1, {a, _}]]
```

Comment: And the complement to your answer: `With[{a = Alternatives @@ L2[[All, 1]]}, 
 DeleteCases[L1, {Except@a, _}]]` :)

Comment: Simon, why use `With` here?  Clarity?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes, just for clarity. Not really necessary here, but I did some work recently with rather complex string patterns and got into the habit of doing this to make `StringCases` and `StringMatchQ` expressions more readable.

Comment: Okay, just checking.  I sometimes use `Function` the same way, e.g. `Alternatives @@ L2[[All, 1]] // Cases[L1, {#, _}] &`.

Comment: Could you tell me if I am wrong: the command With will take the cases in L1 where a could be any of the first elements in the list L2 (2 and 9 for this example)...it is ok?

Comment: @Jotasmall, yes in this example `a` becomes the expression `Alternatives[2, 9]` which is a pattern that matches either 2 or 9.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{2, 1}, {6, 4}, {8, 7}, {9, 5}};
b = {{2, 9}, {9, 6}};
```

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ First @ KeyIntersection[MapApply[Rule] /@ {a, b}]
```

{{2, 1}, {9, 5}}

From Documentation details:

"`KeyIntersection` can be used not only on `Association` objects, but
also on lists of rules."

Answer (score 2):

```
L1 = {{2, 1}, {6, 4}, {8, 7}, {9, 5}};
L2 = {{2, 9}, {9, 6}};
Select[L1, MemberQ[L2[[All, 1]], First@#] &]
(*
{{2, 1}, {9, 5}}
*)
```

Comment: This will reevaluate `L2[[All, 1]]` for every element of `L1`.  This is not ideal for long lists.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `

When deciding whether to optimize a specific part of the program, Amdahl's Law should always be considered: the impact on the overall program depends very much on how much time is actually spent in that specific part, which is not always clear from looking at the code without a performance analysis.`

Answer (score 1):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
L1 = {{2, 1}, {6, 4}, {8, 7}, {9, 5}};
L2 = {{2, 9}, {9, 6}};
L3 = Catenate@{L1, L2};

Catenate@GroupBy[L3, First, If[Length@# > 1, Complement[#, L2], {}] &]

(*{{2, 1}, {9, 5}}*)
```