# Filtering elements from a list that appear only once

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to be able to select elements from a list that only appear once.  I originally had this:

```
Select[Table[Count[list, i], {i, list}], # == 1]
```

But the issue is that my list has about 60,000 elements, and it takes way too long.  The only way I could think of speeding it up would be to make a function like Count, but that would return after seeing the same element twice, and I have no idea how to do that in Mathematica.

Also, I'm not sure if it's important, but the list is actually a list of lines (with a line defined by two 2D points).  The goal is to find the edges that are only used by one triangle, hence making them a perimeter edge.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is one for fun, but it is no where as fast as Belisarius `u = Union[lis]; Pick[u, Count[lis, #] & /@ u, 1];`

Comment: Interesting thing is that Matlab has a build-in function for this exact thing. It is called `unique()` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html

Comment: Related: [(18100)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18100/121)

Comment: `Cases[Tally[yt], {a_, b_ /; b == 1} -> a]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following isn't probably the fastest way, but fast enough for 60K elements:

```
yourList = RandomInteger[10000, 60000];

Select[Tally@yourList, #[[2]] == 1 &][[All, 1]]
```

The Timing in my machine is well under 0.1 sec.

Comment: `Cases[Tally@yourList, {_, 1}][[All, 1]]` is a bit faster for me.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks! Here too yours is a bit faster

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility:

```
Flatten@Cases[Gather@yourList, {_}]
```

**Edit 2.  Just for Fun**

Borrowing from the [efficient method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30611/106) given above by [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius)

```
Pick[#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2]], 1] &@Tally@yourList
```

**Edit**

@[Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) adds the following (surprising to my mind) timing results, comparing my original method (Gather) with [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30611/106) given by [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius):

[image]

Comment: nice. But it slows down alot when the size of the list becomes large. see screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2fFFo.png)

Comment: code for above: `r = Flatten[Last@Reap[Do[
      yourList = RandomInteger[10000, n];
      Sow[{n, 
        Timing[Select[Tally@yourList, #[[2]] == 1 &][[All, 1]]][[1]],
        Timing[Flatten@Cases[Gather@yourList, {_}]][[1]]}]
      , {n, 100000, 6000000, 100000}
      ]], 1]; ListLinePlot[{r[[All, 2]], r[[All, 3]]}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Tally", "Gather"}, PlotLabel -> "CPU time (sec)"]`

Comment: Please double check that the code that generated the plot is correct. The code is above. I did my best to make sure it is correct, and I was also surprised by the result.

Answer (score 7):

This is certainly not fast, but is different from the ones previously posted:

```
onlyOnce[list_] := Block[{f},
    f[x_] := f[1, x] = If[f[1, x], False, False, True];

    Scan[f, list];
    Select[list, f[1, #] &]
]
```

belisarius' is about 10 times faster on my machine.

Comment: The `Listable` attribute seems to interfere with this working with elements that are themselves lists.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, that's the remains from an earlier `Pick` based version I had which did `Pick[list, f[list];f[1,list],True]`. I've removed it now

Answer (score 6):

I've thought that the following method will be fun but not efficient alternative, but it looks like it can be useful:

```
Split@Sort@list /. {Repeated[n_, {2,Infinity}]} :> Sequence[] // Flatten
```

for @belisarius test I have the following timings:

> ```
> 0.053003 (*mine*)
> 0.034002 (*belisarius*)
> ```

but for case where there are less or no unique elements it is comparable or even a little bit faster.

Here is an improvement suggested by Mr. Wizard:

```
Cases[Split@Sort@list, {x_} :> x]
```

which makes this method two times faster than first approach with `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: Nice idea.  Shorter and faster: `Cases[Split@Sort@list, {x_} :> x]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it is faster, thanks. Don't you think that `Sort` shouldn't be so fast in comparison with `Tally`? I was surprised after first timmings. Well, I know both have to scan repeatedly but I thought `Tally` will be much better.

Comment: I don't know; sorts are often very fast so it does not surprise me.  I am also not surprised that different algorithm behind `Tally` is faster in some cases and not in others.

Answer (score 4):

No fresh methods of my own but some improvements:

Same idea as belisarius, slightly different formulation:

```
Cases[Tally @ #, {x_, 1} :> x] &
```

Shorter version of Kuba's method using the same formulation:

```
Cases[Split @ Sort @ list, {x_} :> x]
```

A variation of rm -rf's method:

```
unique[a_List] :=
 Module[{f, g},
   _g = True;
   f[x_] /; g[x] := g[x] = False;
   Scan[f, a];
   Select[a, g]
 ]
```

---

#### Timings

Supporting function and data:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

test = RandomInteger[#, 2 #] &[125000];
```

Tests on version 7:

```
Select[Tally@test, #[[2]] == 1 &][[All, 1]] // timeAvg
Cases[Tally@test, {x_, 1} :> x]             // timeAvg
```

> 0.1902
>
> 0.1498

```
Split@Sort@test /. {Repeated[n_, {2, Infinity}]} :> Sequence[] // Flatten // timeAvg
Cases[Split@Sort@test, {x_} :> x]                                         // timeAvg
```

> 0.1216
>
> 0.0688

```
onlyOnce[test] // timeAvg
unique[test]   // timeAvg
```

> 0.749
>
> 0.609

Comment: You mean, like [Mike's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30610/filtering-elements-from-a-list-that-appear-only-once/30627#comment95312_30611)?

Comment: @rm-rf Well yes, but I prefer the rule form, at least visually.

Comment: @rm-rf Hopefully my extended answer is more pleasing to you.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing data from Dr. belisarius:

```
SeedRandom[1];
yourList = RandomInteger[10000, 60000];
```

**Using `GroupBy`:** (* Timing 0.0156 *)

```
GroupBy[yourList, Identity, Length] // 
 KeyValueMap[If[#2 == 1, #1, Nothing] &]
```

**Using `PositionIndex`:** (* Timing 0.0312 *)

```
PositionIndex[yourList] // 
 KeyValueMap[If[Length@#2 == 1, #1, Nothing] &]
```

---

> {5966, 7867, 5862, 5476, 4417, 446, 971, 6670, 3464, 5600, 5429, 
> 4649, 850, 7912, 6186, 6028, 1567, 7918, 6915, 8541, 4273, 5071, 
> 2436, 9569, 8069, 3315, 3260, 2260, 2472, 1158, 8655, 2526, 8280, 
> 9760, 5055, 404, 9398, 2787, 4347, 5772, 1989, 5910, 7944, 4030, 
> 8199, 7206, 9212, 716, 3757, 7360, 8984, 5067, 7994, 5718, 7045, 
> 3822, 2737, 8907, 502, 1968, 7669, 7673, 6120, 2729, 6801, 7136, 
> 5000, 6306, 8508, 7839, 2026, 7875, 7368, 8385, 4127, 7745, 9691, 
> 5284, 7607, 5964, 3504, 6701, 3433, 1910, 7754, 3969, 6592, 8153, 
> 1503, 5955, 3374, 153, 1022, 6884, 3445, 6490, 4317, 8323, 4951, 
> 3734, 8455, 3132, 2793, 9162, 7370, 4949, 2960, 7246, 8494, 1034, 
> 5704, 7527, 6800, 1582, 1496, 9405, 6016, 2150, 2874, 9232, 6, 9862, 
> 8743, 5682, 8578, 160, 8103, 9294, 8716, 7177, 4775, 7671, 7719, 
> 1666, 1942, 6486, 1670, 7396, 1523, 2322, 2279, 1432, 1202, 9215, 
> 3201, 9204, 2591, 3142, 6944, 9360, 2652, 4765, 9185, 3791, 5548, 
> 8197, 5199}

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1];
yourList = RandomInteger[10000, 60000];

Pick[Keys[#], Values[#], 1] &@Counts[yourList]

(* {5966, 7867, 5862, 5476, 4417,  446,  971, 6670, 3464, 5600, 5429, 
    4649,  850, 7912, 6186, 6028, 1567, 7918, 6915, 8541, 4273, 5071, 
    2436, 9569, 8069, 3315, 3260, 2260, 2472, 1158, 8655, 2526, 8280, 
    9760, 5055,  404, 9398, 2787, 4347, 5772, 1989, 5910, 7944, 4030, 
    8199, 7206, 9212,  716, 3757, 7360, 8984, 5067, 7994, 5718, 7045, 
    3822, 2737, 8907,  502, 1968, 7669, 7673, 6120, 2729, 6801, 7136, 
    5000, 6306, 8508, 7839, 2026, 7875, 7368, 8385, 4127, 7745, 9691, 
    5284, 7607, 5964, 3504, 6701, 3433, 1910, 7754, 3969, 6592, 8153, 
    1503, 5955, 3374,  153, 1022, 6884, 3445, 6490, 4317, 8323, 4951, 
    3734, 8455, 3132, 2793, 9162, 7370, 4949, 2960, 7246, 8494, 1034, 
    5704, 7527, 6800, 1582, 1496, 9405, 6016, 2150, 2874, 9232,    6,
    9862, 8743, 5682, 8578,  160, 8103, 9294, 8716, 7177, 4775, 7671,   
    7719, 1666, 1942, 6486, 1670, 7396, 1523, 2322, 2279, 1432, 1202,
    9215, 3201, 9204, 2591, 3142, 6944, 9360, 2652, 4765, 9185, 3791,
    5548, 8197, 5199} *}
```

A point-free version

```
Pick[Through[Sequence[Keys, Values][Counts[yourList]]], 1]


(* {5966, 7867, 5862, 5476, 4417,  446,  971, 6670, 3464, 5600, 5429, 
    4649,  850, 7912, 6186, 6028, 1567, 7918, 6915, 8541, 4273, 5071, 
    2436, 9569, 8069, 3315, 3260, 2260, 2472, 1158, 8655, 2526, 8280, 
    9760, 5055,  404, 9398, 2787, 4347, 5772, 1989, 5910, 7944, 4030, 
    8199, 7206, 9212,  716, 3757, 7360, 8984, 5067, 7994, 5718, 7045, 
    3822, 2737, 8907,  502, 1968, 7669, 7673, 6120, 2729, 6801, 7136, 
    5000, 6306, 8508, 7839, 2026, 7875, 7368, 8385, 4127, 7745, 9691, 
    5284, 7607, 5964, 3504, 6701, 3433, 1910, 7754, 3969, 6592, 8153, 
    1503, 5955, 3374,  153, 1022, 6884, 3445, 6490, 4317, 8323, 4951, 
    3734, 8455, 3132, 2793, 9162, 7370, 4949, 2960, 7246, 8494, 1034, 
    5704, 7527, 6800, 1582, 1496, 9405, 6016, 2150, 2874, 9232,    6,
    9862, 8743, 5682, 8578,  160, 8103, 9294, 8716, 7177, 4775, 7671,   
    7719, 1666, 1942, 6486, 1670, 7396, 1523, 2322, 2279, 1432, 1202,
    9215, 3201, 9204, 2591, 3142, 6944, 9360, 2652, 4765, 9185, 3791,
    5548, 8197, 5199} *}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];

list = RandomInteger[10000, 60000];

Keys @ Select[Counts @ list, # == 1 &]
```

{5966, 7867, 5862, 5476, 4417, 446, 971, 6670, 3464, 5600, 5429, 
4649, 850, 7912, 6186, 6028, 1567, 7918, 6915, 8541, 4273, 5071, 
2436, 9569, 8069, 3315, 3260, 2260, 2472, 1158, 8655, 2526, 8280, 
9760, 5055, 404, 9398, 2787, 4347, 5772, 1989, 5910, 7944, 4030, 
8199, 7206, 9212, 716, 3757, 7360, 8984, 5067, 7994, 5718, 7045, 
3822, 2737, 8907, 502, 1968, 7669, 7673, 6120, 2729, 6801, 7136, 
5000, 6306, 8508, 7839, 2026, 7875, 7368, 8385, 4127, 7745, 9691, 
5284, 7607, 5964, 3504, 6701, 3433, 1910, 7754, 3969, 6592, 8153, 
1503, 5955, 3374, 153, 1022, 6884, 3445, 6490, 4317, 8323, 4951, 
3734, 8455, 3132, 2793, 9162, 7370, 4949, 2960, 7246, 8494, 1034, 
5704, 7527, 6800, 1582, 1496, 9405, 6016, 2150, 2874, 9232, 6, 9862, 
8743, 5682, 8578, 160, 8103, 9294, 8716, 7177, 4775, 7671, 7719, 
1666, 1942, 6486, 1670, 7396, 1523, 2322, 2279, 1432, 1202, 9215, 
3201, 9204, 2591, 3142, 6944, 9360, 2652, 4765, 9185, 3791, 5548, 
8197, 5199}

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];

list = RandomInteger[10000, 60000];
```

---

A variant using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
Catenate@GroupBy[list, Repeated, If[Length@# == 1, #, {}] &]

{5966, 7867, 5862, 5476, 4417, 446, 971, 6670, 3464, 5600, 5429,
4649, 850, 7912, 6186, 6028, 1567, 7918, 6915, 8541, 4273, 5071,
2436, 9569, 8069, 3315, 3260, 2260, 2472, 1158, 8655, 2526, 8280,
9760, 5055, 404, 9398, 2787, 4347, 5772, 1989, 5910, 7944, 4030,
8199, 7206, 9212, 716, 3757, 7360, 8984, 5067, 7994, 5718, 7045,
3822, 2737, 8907, 502, 1968, 7669, 7673, 6120, 2729, 6801, 7136,
5000, 6306, 8508, 7839, 2026, 7875, 7368, 8385, 4127, 7745, 9691,
5284, 7607, 5964, 3504, 6701, 3433, 1910, 7754, 3969, 6592, 8153,
1503, 5955, 3374, 153, 1022, 6884, 3445, 6490, 4317, 8323, 4951,
3734, 8455, 3132, 2793, 9162, 7370, 4949, 2960, 7246, 8494, 1034,
5704, 7527, 6800, 1582, 1496, 9405, 6016, 2150, 2874, 9232, 6, 9862,
8743, 5682, 8578, 160, 8103, 9294, 8716, 7177, 4775, 7671, 7719,
1666, 1942, 6486, 1670, 7396, 1523, 2322, 2279, 1432, 1202, 9215,
3201, 9204, 2591, 3142, 6944, 9360, 2652, 4765, 9185, 3791, 5548,
8197, 5199}
```