# Complement of multisets

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

Given lists $a$ and $b$, which represent multisets, how can I compute the complement $a\setminus b$?

I'd like to construct a function `xunion` that returns the symmetric difference of multisets.
For example, if $a=\{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3\}$ and $b=\{1, 5, 5, 1\}$, then their symmetric difference is $\big((a\cup b)\setminus(a\cap b)\big)\setminus(a\cap b)=(a\setminus b)\cup(b\setminus a)=\{1,1,2,3,5,5\}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't pretend this is the most efficient or pretty, but here's a go at what I think you're after (see latter part of post for faster and simpler realizations):

```
a = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3};
b = {1, 5, 5, 1};

result = Join[
    Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ 
      Flatten[Replace[Cases[GatherBy[Join[Tally[#1], Tally[#2]], First],
              {{Alternatives @@ a, _} ..}], {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> 
                                            {{a, Max[0, b - d]}}, 1], 1]],
    Flatten[
     ConstantArray @@@ 
      Flatten[Replace[Cases[GatherBy[Join[Tally[#2], Tally[#1]], First], 
              {{Alternatives @@ b, _} ..}], {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> 
                                            {{a, Max[0, b - d]}}, 1], 1]]] &[a, b]

(* {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5} *)
```

Here's a *much* faster alternative for big lists:

```
Module[{ta = Tally[#1], tb = Tally[#2], tab, tba, j},

   tab = Tally[Join[#1, #2]][[;; Length@ta]];
   ta[[All, 2]] = ta[[All, 2]] - (tab - ta)[[All, 2]];

   tba = Tally[Join[#2, #1]][[;; Length@tb]];
   tb[[All, 2]] = tb[[All, 2]] - (tba - tb)[[All, 2]];

   j = Join[ta, tb];

   Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ Pick[j, Sign[j[[All, 2]]], 1]]] &[a, b]
```

And after partitioning a steak and doing a gatherby on dessert, this simpler and even faster idea popped into the cranium:

```
With[{du = DeleteDuplicates@Join[#1, #2]},
     Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ 
       Transpose[{du, Abs[Subtract[Tally[Join[du, #1]], Tally[Join[du, #2]]][[All, 2]]]}]] &[a, b]
```

Comment: `Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Flatten[{Tally /@ {a, b} //. {{a___, {n_, x_}, b___}, {c___, {n_, y_}, d___}} :> {{a, b}, {c, d, {n,Abs[ x - y]}}}, 1]`

Comment: @belisarius: Yeah, I pondered such a mostly rule/replace solution, but *agonizingly* slow on larger problems. `BlankNullSequence`... the performance killer.

Comment: Yup, that is why I haven't posted it as an answer. ReplaceRepeated and `___` always tend to indulge a nap

Comment: Your answer is the multiSymmetricDifference. Could you please also add the multiComplement, so I can accept?

Answer (score 6):

Here's my version.

```
Clear[multiComplement];
multiComplement[a_, b_] :=
  Join @@ (ConstantArray[First@#, Max[Last@#, 0]] & /@ (Tally[a] /. 
   (Tally[b] /. {e_, c_Integer} :> {e, k_Integer} -> {e, k - c})));
```

In action:

```
With[{a = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3}, b = {1, 5, 5, 1}},
   multiComplement[a, b]~Join~multiComplement[b, a]
]
```

> `{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5}`

It appears essentially the same as rasher's (who is indeed 10 minutes rasher).  The main points are using `Tally` to get a count of how often each element appears.  Then using rules to pick out the same elements in the tally on the other set.  Working out the tally difference, and ignore the negative count `Max[0, ...]`.  Finally the new tally is expanded with `ConstantArray`.

Comment: +1 on the tally idea (had some though, see update) - but strangely (have not analyzed it yet deeply) yours gets very slow with larger lists and many distinct elements (I'm guessing the replace is the killer...)

Comment: I tend to use rules quite a lot because I think it is very clear what they do (although I admit the answer here is quite obfuscated).  And yes, the performance does degrade with larger lists.  But we don't want to prematurely optimise.

Answer (score 5):

Another way (slower than rasher's):

```
Clear[simComplement];
simComplement[a_, b_] := Join @@ (Fold[DeleteCases[#1, #2, {1}, 1] &, #[[1]], 
                                       Join@#[[2]]] & /@ {{a, b}, {b, a}})

With[{a = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3}, b = {1, 5, 5, 1}}, simComplement[a, b]]
(*
 {2, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this question is nearly a duplicate of [Removing elements from a list which appear in another list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18100/121) but since this one allows other, potentially better, solutions it should not be closed.
To illustrate, using Leonid's `unsortedComplement` or my `removeFrom2`:

```
a = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3};
b = {1, 5, 5, 1};

unsortedComplement[a, b] ~Join~ unsortedComplement[b, a] // Sort

removeFrom2[a, b] ~Join~ removeFrom2[b, a] // Sort
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5}
>
> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5}
> ```

Unfortunately rasher's solution from that question doesn't appear to be directly applicable here.

Comment: +1, forgot about that neat question. Yeah, using that method from the linked question is a lot of baggage for the simpler problem here...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that question and LS' `unsortedComplement`: I adapted the method I used above to a plain unsorted complement that is from 3X to over an order of magnitude faster than LS' version.

Answer (score 0):

`DeleteElements`, new in V 13.1, simplifies this task considerably:

```
a = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3};
b = {1, 5, 5, 1};
```

Since `DeleteElements` works from left to right, we have to use `Reverse` twice.

```
com[{x_, y_}] :=
 Reverse @ DeleteElements[Reverse @ x, Rule @@ Reverse @ Transpose @ Tally[y]]

com[{a, b}]~Join~com[{b, a}]
```

{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5}