# How to subtract one list from another, treating each elements as distinct, assuming the smaller list is a subset of the larger list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that I have two lists of different sizes, the smaller of which is a subset of the larger, e.g.

```
a = {"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"}
b = {"A", "B"}
```

How can I subtract `b` from `a`, treating each element as distinct, such that the result is `{"A", "A", "B", "C"}`?

One solution I can think of is to use

```
Merge[{Counts[a], -Counts[b]}, Total]
```

then reconstruct the result somehow, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Please, hold on with an accept. Better answers may appear. Let's do not discourage others. :)

Comment: @Kuba As I've asked for *a simpler way*, marking your answer as accepted is appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, a, b]
```

> ```
> {"A", "A", "B", "C"}
> ```

Comment: Thoroughly inefficient due to repeated search and array reallocation but still beautiful. +1 :-)

Answer (score 7):

For efficiency, treat them as variables and let Plus do the work:

```
List @@ (Plus @@ a - Plus @@ b)
```

and convert to a list if you want:

```
{"A", 2 "B", -3 "C"} /. (n_*v_ :> 
   Sequence @@ ConstantArray[v,n])
(* => {"A", "B"} *)
```

**Update** 
Kuba's solution is elegant but not efficient nor does it maintain a sorted order, look at the performance:

```
In[1]:= {a, b} = Map[
   FromCharacterCode /@ RandomInteger[{67, 77}, #] &, {100000, 
    10000}];

In[2]:= AbsoluteTiming[Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, a, b]]
Out[2]= $Aborted (* still running after 20 seconds... *)

In[3]:= AbsoluteTiming[List @@ (Plus @@ a - Plus @@ b)]
Out[3]= {0.041489, {8114 "C", 8177 "D", 8182 "E", 8328 "F", 
  8123 "G", 7934 "H", 8191 "I", 8267 "J", 8348 "K", 8223 "L", 
  8113 "M"}}
```

Comment: Then convert `{2 "A", "B", "C"}` back to `{"A", "A", "B", "C"}` somehow?

Comment: @Kuba I need the list to be in the `{"A", "A", ...}` form.

Comment: @Taiki `List @@ (Plus @@ a - Plus @@ b) /. Times[n_, var_] :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[var, n]` works.

Comment: @kuba that case won't happen after the Plus is applied

Comment: @Öskå right, updated the answer

Comment: @M.R. I know, I was just thinking about input `a = {2"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"}
b = {"A", "B"}` and expected output `{2 "A", "A", "B", "C"}`.

Comment: @kuba even if it is really slow I like your answer, but I like the mathiness of this approach

Comment: @Taiki perhaps you don't need a solution that scales?

Comment: Lol, @kuba silly me!

Comment: @kuba made the change

Comment: @kuba it did terminate at 25 seconds

Comment: @M.R. I agree it is not the best. Pattern matching + separate scan for each `b` elements is not the best idea. It looks nice though :P

Comment: @M.R. I do, but I just couldn't mark two answers as accepted. I've upvoted your answer though.

Answer (score 5):

To *reconstruct the result somehow*:

```
reconstructF=Join@@ConstantArray@@@Normal@#&;

reconstructF@Merge[Total][{Counts[a],- Counts[b]}]
(* {"A", "A", "B", "C"} *)
```

Comment: This is also pretty fast.

Answer (score 4):

If (a) *preserving the order of the minuend list* and (b) *respecting the order of the subtrahend list* are important to you (or to someone else reading this post), here's a neat solution that seems to perform well:

```
listComplement1[a_List, b_List] :=
 Module[{j = 1},
  With[{bn = Length@b},
   Select[a, j > bn || # =!= b[[j]] || ++j &]
   ]
  ]

listComplement1[a, b]

(* Out: {"C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C"} *)
```

And just because I can, here's a semi-compiled version that uses integer codes for distinct elements! Wheee!

```
listComplement2Helper =
  Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{j = 1},
    With[{bn = Length@b},
     Select[a,
      If[j > bn || # =!= b[[j]],
        True,
        ++j; False
        ] &
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];

listComplement2[a_List, b_List] := 
 With[{rels = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, DeleteDuplicates@a]},
  With[
   {fwdMap = Dispatch@Append[rels, _ -> 0],
    revMap = Dispatch[Reverse /@ rels]},
   Replace[
    listComplement2Helper[
     Replace[a, fwdMap, {1}],
     Replace[b, fwdMap, {1}]],
    revMap,
    {1}
    ]
   ]
  ]

listComplement2[a, b]

(* Out: {"C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C"} *)
```

At first I thought that integer codes could speed things up when the list elements are (a) very many, (b) very complicated, and (c) very similar, but now I'm thinking it won't help much (if at all) due to the comparisons that have to happen anyway for `DeleteDuplicates`... Oh well, still fun.

---

*Caveat:* All elements in `b` after the first element in `b` that is not also in `a` will not be removed from `a`.

---

*Note:* This answer previously also suggested a solution using [`SequenceAlignment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceAlignment.html). Unfortunately, this approach doesn't seem to work. I couldn't figure out a nice way to adapt `SequenceAlignment` to the requirements here.

Comment: Sadly it seems that the `SequenceAlignment` method is not correct.  Consider for example: `a = {3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 2}; b = {2, 5, 4, 3, 0}` -- the result should be `{1, 0, 0, 5, 2}` but instead it gives `{3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2}`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you're right. Playing with it just now, it seems like `SequenceAlignment` is probably just ill-suited for this. (Or I'm not seeing how to use it correctly.) Thanks for pointing out this error. Answer's now updated.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, incidentally, +1 for [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75582/117). Very, very neat.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, quite a puzzling ellipsis there. Text lacks tone, though, so what's it for?

Comment: That was just because of the minimum character requirement for comments.  I did not realize the confusion I created.  I'll be more verbose in the future.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, ah! [facepalm] I completely forgot the comment minimum. I thought I had erred in some informal MSE cultural etiquette and was being gently if vaguely reprimanded, so I was treading lightly... I do feel silly, lol. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No problem.  I am glad you asked.  Please always do if something seems "off" like that; no need to guess.

Comment: ps I forgot to up-vote after you addressed the `SequenceAlignment` problem.  corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {2 "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"};
b = {"A", "B"}; 

Delete[a, First[Position[a, #, 1]] & /@ b]
(*{2 "A", "A", "B", "C"}*)
```