# How does this code work to substract a set A from a set B?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, symbolic

In an answer to a question (as given here:  [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/removing-elements-from-a-list-which-appear-in-another-list)), the proposed function was to to subtract a set B from a Set A:

```
removeFrom2[b_List, a_List] := Module[{f, g},
  (f[#] = -#2) & @@@ Tally[a];
  g[x_] /; f[x] < 0 := f[x]++;
  g[_] = True;
  Select[b, g]
]
```

I cannot understand how that code works.  Especially lines 2 and 3 remain a mistery. Can someone explain to me what is meant by line 2 (what I understand is, g[x]=f[x]++ if f[x]<0 (is it a sort of loop?)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm just going to walk through all of it. If something is too pedantic, skip it.

`Module[{f,g}...`

creates a scoping construct so the definitions of  `f` and `g` are local to this code.

`Tally[a]` produces a list of all the elements in `a` and a count for each element. For instance, `Tally[{a,a,b,c,a,d,d}]` would give `{{a,3},{b,1},{c,1},{d,2}}`.

The strange notation `f[#] = -#2&@@@Tally[a]` is equivalent to looping over the list returned by`Tally[a]` and assigning the count of element `j` to `f[j]`. So in the example above `f[a] = -3, f[b] = -1, f[c] = -1, f[d] = -2`. You can read about pure functions, slots, and Apply in the docs to make sense of the notation here. (N.B. The `-#2` should probably be `-(#2+1)`, since this doesn't seem to handle duplicates correctly as-is).

Now we define the criterion function `g`. `Select` will apply this function to the list `b` and select any element for which `g[element] = True`. The line

`g[x_]/; f[x]< 0 := f[x]++;`

says for any value of x such that `f[x]<0` `g[x] := f[x]++;` (`/;` is called a `Condition` if you want to look it up and can be read as 'such that'). The `:=` is `SetDelayed` meaning the value of `g[x]` is recomputed each time using the current value of `f`. So as we select `x` from `b`, `f[x]` is incremented, and `g[x]` checks the condition again the next time it's called. Notice that if we ask for a value of `f` that hasn't been defined, for instance, using the `a` I defined above `f[q]` returns `f[q]`, which won't pass the test given by the condition.

So what if we've incremented `f[i]` to the point that `f[i] = 0` or otherwise fails the test in the condition? MMA will look for another definition for `g` that may apply until it runs out of definitions to try (which is what happened when I asked for `f[q]`). But, here we've provided a default definition that will apply for any argument, so MMA falls back to `g[_]=True`. (You can read more about `UpValues` and `DownValues` if you're curious how this stuff works.)

As `Select` loops through the `i` elements in list `b` it asks what `g[ b[[i]] ]` is, if the number is negative the counter for that value is increased. If we encounter the same number again, the counter is increased again, unless the counter is now `0`. If that's the case we fall back to our default definition of `g` which returns `True`, and we take that number. We skip over any number for which `g` does not return `True`. Since we only defined `f` for values in the list `a` any value not in list `a` automatically returns `True`. If a value `j` appeared in the list `a` `n` times we only select `j` once we've seen `n` of them, such that `f[j]=0` and `g` is `True` by default.

---

The fact that `Select` moves element by element keeping track of `f` without doing some clever parallel task with copies of `f` behind the scenes is beyond my understanding. @Mr.Wizard usually knows what he's doing though, and it seems to work. Maybe he'd be willing to comment on that bit.