# SubsetQ[] without ignoring duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

How could one create a code that checks whether a set is a subset of another, but not ignoring the duplicates? For example, $\{1,1,1\}$ would be a subset of $\{1,1,1,1\}$, but not vice versa. `SubsetQ` ignores duplicates, which is not desired.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can adapt the solutions from [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/removing-elements-from-a-list-which-appear-in-another-list?lq=1), which is about set subtraction where the sets can have multiple elements the same.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like [`Counts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html) for this:

```
SubmultisetQ[list1_, list2_] :=
 With[{c1 = Counts[list1], c2 = Counts[list2]},
  SubsetQ[Keys@c1, Keys@c2] &&
   AllTrue[MapThread[GreaterEqual, KeyIntersection[{c1, c2}]],
    Identity]];

SubmultisetQ[{1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]
(* True *)

SubmultisetQ[{1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Proposition**

Here is a pattern-matching approach:

```
Attributes[oList] = Orderless;
sublistQ[{s1___}, {s2___}] := MatchQ[oList[s1], oList[s2, ___]];
```

Taking the examples of Pillsy:

```
sublistQ[{1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]
(* True *)

sublistQ[{1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]
(* False *)
```

**Proposition 2** *(update)*

This alternative is faster (see below for updated timings):

```
sublist2Q[l_List, {s___}] := MatchQ[l, {OrderlessPatternSequence[s, ___]}]
```

**Timings**

The best performance amongst the solutions proposed so far will depend on the structure of the input lists. (And so does the scaling for each of them.)

As a few examples, here `sublistQ` and `sublist2Q` perform better

```
list = Range[10^5];
list1 = RandomSample[list, 10^5];
list2 = RandomSample[list, 10^4];

SubmultisetQ[list1, list2] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.69972, True} *)

MultiplicitySubsetQ[list1, list2] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.573459, True} *)

sublistQ[list1, list2] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0750208, True} *)

sublist2Q[list1, list2] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0639587, True} *)
```

while in what follows `SubmultisetQ` is the fastest

```
list1 = RandomInteger[10, 10^5];
list2 = RandomInteger[10, 5];

SubmultisetQ[list1, list2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00025, True} *)

MultiplicitySubsetQ[list1, list2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.105, True} *)

sublistQ[list1, list2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.029, True} *)

sublist2Q[list1, list2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.027, True} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
ContainsElements[set_, elements_] := Module[{labels, counts},
  {labels, counts} = Transpose@Tally[elements];
  SubsetQ[set, elements] && And @@ GreaterEqual @@@ Transpose[{labels /. Rule @@@ Tally[set], counts}]
  ]
```

Examples:

```
ContainsElements[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]
(* True *)

ContainsElements[{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
(* False *)
```

Comment: ``ContainsElements[{1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}]`` seems to return ``True``.

Comment: Adding ``SubsetQ[set,elements]&&`` in front of the ``Module`` fixed it.

Comment: Alright, updated.

Answer (score 3):

The function `CoefficientList` would work for sets with only nonnegative integers:

```
MultiplicitySubsetQ[lset_, sset_] := 
 Module[{x}, 
  AllTrue[CoefficientList[Total[x^lset] - Total[x^sset], x], # >= 0 &]
 ]
```

This would work for all sets:

```
MultiplicitySubsetQ[lset_, sset_] := 
 Module[{x}, 
  AllTrue[List @@ (Total[x^lset] - Total[x^sset]) /. x -> 1, # >= 0 &]
 ]
```