# Removing every member of a list from another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists A={{1,2},{3,6},{7,8},{5,0}}, and another list of lists B={{1,2},{5,0}}. If any list in B is also in A, I want to remove them  from A. E.g.,Taking {1,2} and {5,0} out of A to get {{3,6},{7,8}}.

Comment: Have you seen `Complement[]`?

Comment: Aside from J.M's suggestion, you can also take a look at this: [18100](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/removing-elements-from-a-list-which-appear-in-another-list)

Comment: Complement works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Complement treats its inputs and output as sets.  This means that the result will be sorted and duplicates will be removed.  Is this a problem for your application?