# Merging the knots vector to get the common knots vector

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Given that I have the following knots vector `U1, U2, U3`

```
U1 = {0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8};
U2 = {0.21, 0.25, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8};
U3 = {0.25, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8};
```

Now I would like to calculate their ***common knots vector*** , i.e., a knots vector that contains all of the elements of  `U1, U2, U3` and has the least length. For example, containing all of the elements of  `U1` means containing 
`{0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}`, rather than `{0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.8}`.

Then with the help of *common knots vector*, I want to compute the ***complementary elements*** of each knots vector. For this case, the common knots vector is:

```
commonKnotsVector = {0.21, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}
```

and the corresponding *complementary elements* are

```
(*
 U1 --> {0.21, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7}
 U2 --> {0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75}
 U3 --> {0.21, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.75}
*)
```

---

For the *common knots vector*, my algorithm as shown below:

[image]

```
commonKnotsVector[knots_] :=
  Module[{step1, step2, step3, step4},
   step1 = SortBy[Join @@ Tally /@ knots, First];
   step2 = GatherBy[step1, First];
   step3 = Last /@ (SortBy[#, Last] & /@ step2);
   step4 = step3 /. {x_, n_} :> ConstantArray[x, n];
   Flatten[step4]
]

commonKnotsVector[{u1, u2, u3}]
(*{0.21, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}*)
```

For the complementary elements,

[image]

```
knotsVectorMinus[commonKnotsVector_, knots_] := 
  Module[{step1, step2},
   step1 = GatherBy[Join[Tally@commonKnotsVector, Tally[knots]], First];
   step2 = step1 /. {{{x_, n1_}, {x_, n2_}} :>{x, Abs[n1 - n2]},
                     {{x_, n1_}} :> {x, n1}};
   Flatten[step2 /. {x_, n_} :> ConstantArray[x, n]]
 ]

knotsVectorMinus[commonKnotsVector, #] & /@ {u1, u2, u3}
(*{{0.21, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7}, 
  {0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75}, 
  {0.21, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.75}}*)
```

I think my method is not the best/efficient, so I asked this question to seek other ***elegnant/effective*** solution.

Comment: Isn't there already an algorithm for this in Piegl/Tiller?

Comment: The second operation is equivalent to [(18100)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18100/121).  I am now trying to see if I can use that to craft a method that is over-all faster than Kuba's code.

Comment: Why goodbye ShutaoTang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If order does not matter and it is not meant to be C fast:

```
reCounts = Catenate @* KeyValueMap[ConstantArray];

c = Counts /@ {U1, U2, U3};
m = Merge[c, Max];
commKV = reCounts @ m
```

> ```
> {0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8, 0.21, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7}
> ```

```
compEl = reCounts@Merge[KeyUnion[{m, #}, 0 &], Apply[Subtract]] & /@ c
```

> ```
> {{0.21, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7}, 
>  {0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75}, 
>  {0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.21, 0.6}
> }
> ```

Depending of application, this may be useful:

```
Merge[KeyUnion[Counts /@ {U1, U2, U3}, 0 &], {Max[#], Max[#] - #} &]
```

> ```
> <|0.25 -> {2, {0, 1, 1}}, 
>   0.5 -> {2, {0, 2, 2}}, 
>   ... 
>   value -> {counts in commonKV, {counts in specific compV}}
>  |>
> ```

in one line you have all information, now the question is what do you want to do with this.

Comment: @ShutaoTang I must say I find them useful :)