# removal of pattern from a sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
 lst1 = {a,b,c,d,b,e,c}
```

and:

```
 lst2 = {b,c}
```

I am interested in removing all occurrences of lst2 from lst1, producing:

```
res = {a,d,b,e,c}
```

This is not exactly the same as  [Removing elements from a list which appear in another list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/removing-elements-from-a-list-which-appear-in-another-list); thank you for any thoughts.

Comment: `lst1 //. {start___, Sequence @@ lst2, end___} :> {start, end}`

Comment: What if lst1 = {a,b,a,b,a} and lst2 = {a,b,a}? Should your output be {b,a} or {a,b} or { } ?

Comment: @dan7geo: it would be {}; thanks bob, will play around some more with it.

Comment: You need to  specify in which way this question actually differs.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this does not work (according to the documentation it should, or please tell me what I am doing wrong)

`SequenceCases[lst1, lst2 ->{}, Overlaps -> True]`

A work around would be first computing the positions to be deleted:

`toBeDeleted = Flatten[Range[Sequence @@ #] & /@ SequencePosition[lst1, lst2, Overlaps -> True], 1]`

And then delete these positions:

`Delete[lst1, {#} & /@ toBeDeleted]`