# Delete one item in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of 4 elements `{a, b, c, d}`.

One of the elements has been assigned to a variable, say `y`, at some point in the program.

I am looking for a command that will delete the element of the list that is the same as `y`, BUT if two, three, or four of the elements are the same as `y`, I only want to delete one of the elements that are the same.

For example, say `y=2` and `list={1, 2, 4, 6}`. I want the new list to be `{1, 4, 6}`.

For another example, say `y=5` and `list={3, 5, 5, 5}`. I want the new list to be `{3, 5, 5}`.

Comment: Look at `Drop[...]`

Comment: The problem I was having with Drop is that I don't know which element (1st, 2nd, 3rd, or 4th) y will end up being.

Comment: I'll use Position with Drop, just found that. Thank you

Comment: At least closely related: [18100](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18100/5478), if at the end you want to delete multiple entries at once then this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

How about [`FirstPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html):

```
y = 2;
list = {1, 2, 4, 6};
pos = FirstPosition[list, y]
```

> {2}

```
Drop[list, pos]
```

> {1, 4, 6}

and

```
y = 5;
list = {3, 5, 5, 5};
pos = FirstPosition[list, y]
```

> {2}

```
Drop[list, pos]
```

> {3, 5, 5}

Answer (score 4):

Offered for brevity and style:

```
drop[x_][h_[a___, x_, b___]] := h[a, b]
```

Tests:

```
{1, 2, 4, 6} // drop[2]

drop[5] /@ {{3, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 2, 1, 5}}

foo[m, a, t, h, e, m, a, t, i, c, a] // drop[m] // drop[t]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 6}
>
> {{3, 5, 5}, {2, 1, 5}}
>
> foo[a, h, e, m, a, t, i, c, a]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This also works although, I think, less efficiently than corey979's method.

```
removeFirst[x_?NumericQ, nums : {_?NumericQ ..}] := 
  Drop[nums, Catch[MapIndexed[If[#1 == x, Throw[#2], Nothing] &, nums]]]
```

#### Test cases

```
removeFirst[2, {1, 2, 4, 6}]
```

> `{1, 4, 6}`

```
removeFirst[5, {3, 5, 5, 5}]
```

> `{3, 5, 5}`

When 1st argument is not found in 2nd argument, returns 2nd argument.

```
removeFirst[2, {3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

> `{3, 4, 5, 6}`

Handles case where 1st argument is integer and 2nd is list of reals.

```
removeFirst[2, Range[1., 3., .5]]
```

> `{1., 1.5, 2.5, 3.}`

Handles symbolic numbers.

```
removeFirst[Pi, {E, Pi, E, Pi}]
```

> `{E, E, Pi}`

Answer (score 3):

```
DeleteCases[list, y, 1, 1]
```

> {3, 5, 5}

where

```
list = {3, 5, 5, 5};
y = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since V 13.1 there is `DeleteElements`:

```
list = {1, 2, 4, 6};

DeleteElements[list, 1 -> {2}]
```

{1, 4, 6}

```
list = {3, 5, 5, 5};

DeleteElements[list, 1 -> {5}]
```

{3, 5, 5}

```
list = {2, 3, 5, 5, 5};

DeleteElements[list, {1, 2} -> {2, 5}]
```

{3, 5}

Answer (score 1):

```
drop[x_][list_] := ReplacePart[list, FirstPosition[list, x] :> Sequence[]]
```