# Delete all French stopwords

Tags: string-manipulation, natural-language

I have a list of french stopwords:

```
frenchStopWords = {"alors", "au", "aucuns", "aussi", "autre", "avant", "avec", "avoir", \
"bon", "car", "ce", "cela", "ces", "ceux", "chaque", "ci", "comme", \
"comment", "dans", "des", "du", "dedans", "dehors", "depuis", \
"devrait", "doit", "donc", "dos", "début", "elle", "elles", "en", \
"encore", "essai", "est", "et", "eu", "fait", "faites", "fois", \
"font", "hors", "ici", "il", "ils", "je", "juste", "la", "le", "les", \
"leur", "là", "ma", "maintenant", "mais", "mes", "mine", "moins", \
"mon", "mot", "même", "ni", "nommés", "notre", "nous", "ou", "où", \
"par", "parce", "pas", "peut", "peu", "plupart", "pour", "pourquoi", \
"quand", "que", "quel", "quelle", "quelles", "quels", "qui", "sa", \
"sans", "ses", "seulement", "si", "sien", "son", "sont", "sous", \
"soyez", "sujet", "sur", "ta", "tandis", "tellement", "tels", "tes", \
"ton", "tous", "tout", "trop", "très", "tu", "voient", "vont", \
"votre", "vous", "vu", "ça", "étaient", "état", "étions", "été", \
"être"};
```

And some french text here:

```
text = {"et", "bien", "bonjour,", "vous", "avez", "déjà", "suivi,", \
"peut-être", "le", "cours", "electronique", "et,", "voilà,", "ça", "c\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]est", "le", "cours", "electronique", "ii,", "c\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]est", "une", "suite", "logique", "du", "premier", \
"cours,", "dans", "le", "premier", "cours", "dans", "l\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]électronique", ",", "étudié,", "tout", "ce", "qui", \
"était", "lié", "aux", "fonctions,", "électroniques", "basées", \
"sur", "les", "amplificateurs,", "opérationnels.", "dans", "ce", \
"cours", "là,,", "va", "aborder", "le", "transistor", "bipolaire,", \
"et", "les", "fonctions", "analogiques", "de", "base.,", "donc", \
"va", "partir", "avec", "toutes,", "les", "fonctions", "de", "base", \
"depuis", "l\[CloseCurlyQuote]analyse,", "du", "transistor", "jusqu\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]à", "ce", "qu\[CloseCurlyQuote],", "arrive", \
"avec", "des", "fonctions", "un", "peu,", "plus", "complexes,", "du", \
"style", "analyser", "un,", "régulateur", "série", "et", "terminer", \
"avec,", "l\[CloseCurlyQuote]analyse", "des", "circuits", "tels", \
"que,", "les", "amplificateurs", "de", "puissance,", "et", "les", \
"amplificateurs", "audio.", "donc", "si", "regarde", "ce", "cours,,", \
"va", "se", "rendre", "compte", "que", "la", "suite,", "d\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]electronique", "c\[CloseCurlyQuote]est", \
"electronique", "ii", ".,", "je", "vais", "aller", "dans", "ce", \
"cours,", "et", "voir", "ce", "qui", "va", "se", "passer.,", "je", \
"vais", "aller", "là-dedans,", "et", "voir", "comment", "c\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]est", "structuré", "ce", "cours.,", "donc,", \
"exactement", "de", "la", "même", "manière", "que", "electronique", \
",", "va", "trouver,", "les", "semaines.,", "il", "y", "l\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]équivalent", "de", "8", "semaines,", "d\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]études,", "dont", "deux", "examens.,", "un", \
"examen"};
```

Now I want to delete all stopwords. I tried:

```
DeleteCases[text,#]&/@frenchStopWords
```

...but this is wrong. I know that I need to use an "OR" operator, but I don't know how to implment it without running a for loop. Thanks.

Comment: `Complement[text, frenchStopWords]`

Comment: @james: As well as the nice Comment, see "New Proposal" at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18100/removing-elements-from-a-list-which-appear-in-another-list. Too bad https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteStopwords.html does not have language Options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Alternatives` are often overlooked `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[text, Alternatives@@frenchStopWords]
```

While `Complement` in the comments seems equivalent, it does not accept patterns, and `DeleteCases` does, which would account for more general cases. This is why it is useful to remember `Alternatives` usage in `DeleteCases`.

Comment: thank you very much ! I did not know about Alternatives indeed !