# Complement[] changes order of elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, sorting

Consider this example:

```
Complement[{a, y, c, d, e}, {a, c}, {d}]
(*{e, y}*)
```

However, I was expecting the result to be:

```
(*{y,e}*)
```

Why did `Complement[]` reorder the resulting list?

Any idea how to get the desired results (list with elements in their original order), using `Complement[]`?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/862

Comment: may be not related but instead easily found in the documentation. I was look for explanations why Complement sorts the results (the documentation says it is stored internally).

Comment: @Simon Why not vote to close?

Comment: Also related: [(18100)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18100)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it was late and I was too lazy to properly check if both questions were asking the same thing, so I just posted the link in case anyone else was looking for it. As there are still no close votes I guess the community consensus is that it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses sorting internally (as documented, actually). For unsorted, could do as below.

```
unsortedComplement[l1_, l2_] := Reap[Module[
    {remove},
    Map[(remove[#] = True) &, l2];
    Map[If[TrueQ[remove[#]], Null, Sow[#]] &, l1];
    Clear[remove];
    ]][[2, 1]]

unsortedComplement[{1, 3, 2, 8, 5}, {3, 6}]

(* Out[78]= {1, 2, 8, 5} *)
```

Extending to more lists is straightforward.`enter code here`

Comment: Thanks. there are so many other ways to get the desired results. I was just wondering if there is any way to tell Complement to unsort the result. perhaps I should have read the document carefully. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

This should get you the desired result:

```
 Select[{a, y, c, d, e}, MemberQ[Union[{a, c}, {d}], #] == False &]
```

> {y, e}

Answer (score 6):

If you want to stick with `Complement[]`

```
l = {a, y, c, d, e};;
l[[Sort[Complement[l, {a, c}, {d}] /. Thread[l -> Range@Length@l]]]]
(*{y, e}*)
```

or

```
SortBy[Complement[l, {a, c}, {d}], Position[l, #] &]
(*{y, e}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {a, y, c, d, e};
lb = {a, c};
lc = {d};
```

Since V 13.1 we have `DeleteElements` and `UniqueElements`

```
DeleteElements[la, Join[lb, lc]]
```

{y, e}

```
UniqueElements[{la, lb, lc}]
```

{{y, e}, {}, {}}

```
First[%]
```

{y, e}

Answer (score 2):

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[{a, y, c, d, e}, Alternatives @@ Union @@ {{a, c}, {d}}]

(*{y, e}*)
```