# Removing specific entries from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the list

```
L=8;
indx = Range[-π, π, 2 π/L]
(* {-π, -((3 π)/4), -(π/2), -(π/4), 0, π/4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π} *)
```

Now I want to delete specific elements of this list, e.g `-(π/2), 0,  (3 π)/4`

I make a new list which includes the values I wish to delete, i.e:

```
exvals={-(π/2), 0,  (3 π)/4};
```

and

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[exvals], i++, indx = DeleteCases[indx, exvals[[i]]]]
indx
(*={-π, -(π/2), -(π/4), π/4, (3 π)/4, π} *)
```

which works fine. I am wondering if there is a more compact way to do it without using `For`

Comment: `DeleteCases[indx, exvals]` (should not change sorting order) or `Complement[indx, exvals]` (will return sorted list).

Comment: also `DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ exvals]@indx`.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. I was not aware of `Complement`. Please post it as a reply

Comment: @kglr Thanks. Your suggestion also works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways come to mind, which have different consequences on the ordering of the results. To show that, let me create a scrambled version of your list, so it is not ordered in numerical value:

```
L = 8;
indx = Range[-π, π, 2 π/L];

SeedRandom[20210103]
scrambled = RandomSample[indx]

(*Out: {π, π/2, -((3 π)/4), -(π/2), (3 π)/4, -π, -(π/4), π/4, 0} *)
```

You can then use [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) or [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) to achieve functionally similar results, but with or without sorting the output, respectively:

```
DeleteCases[scrambled, Alternatives @@ exvals]
(* Out: {π, π/2, -((3 π)/4), -π, -(π/4), π/4} *)

Complement[scrambled, exvals]
(* Out: {-π, -((3 π)/4), -(π/4), π/4, π/2, π} *)
```

Comment: I should probably also mention the implementation of `unsortedComplement[]` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59369).

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Range[10];

del = {3, 7, 8};
```

**1.**

Using `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
DeleteElements[list, del]
```

{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10}

Unlike `Complement` `DeleteElements` doesn't sort

```
DeleteElements[Reverse @ list, del]
```

{10, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1}

**2.**

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
p = Position[list, Alternatives @@ del]
```

{{3}, {7}, {8}}

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ list
```

{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Range[10];

del = {3, 7, 8};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[Nothing, #, Position[#, Alternatives @@ del]] &@list

(*{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10}*)
```

Or using `SubsetMap`:

```
p = Position[list, Alternatives @@ del];

f = Array[Inactive[Nothing] &, Length@p];

Activate@SubsetMap[f &, list, p]

(*{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10}*)
```