# Removing certain numbers from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

If I have a list of numbers `{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79}`, is there a way to remove the list `{2, 4, 56}` from that list?

In my application, the lists are way bigger, so I am looking for a general way of removing a list of numbers from the original list.

My thoughts were to use the following code: `DeleteCases[{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79}, {2, 4, 56}]` but that didn't work, because the output must be `{1, 70, 11, 20, 79}` and it isn't.

Comment: You coud try: DeleteCases[{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79}, 
 x_ /; MemberQ[{2, 4, 56}, x]]

Comment: Just a little correction of your code `DeleteCases[{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79}, Alternatives@@{2,4,56}]` should do the trick.

Comment: Strongly related: [How to Delete Elements from List1 appearing in List2?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/106)

Comment: Also, [unsorted complement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59369/106)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three main ways of deleting members in such cases :

1. As Daniel said , you could try `DeleteCases` supplementing a pattern which picks up just the numbers which are element of another list. The pattern is like this :

as what Daniel said :

```
a_ /; MemberQ[{2,4,56},a]
```

or :

```
a_?(MemberQ[{2, 4, 56}, #] &)
```

Now you could use each one of the above patterns in `DeleteCases`. Thus we have :

```
DeleteCases[{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79} , a_ /; MemberQ[{2,4,56},a])]
```

or :

```
DeleteCases[{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79} , a_?(MemberQ[{2, 4, 56}, #] &)]
```

2. But there is even a simpler way of deleting cases which could be tried.

This is a sample :

```
{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79} /. a_ /; MemberQ[{2, 4, 56}, a] -> Nothing
```

In this way we could just convert any instance matching your pattern to `Nothing` ! ( Converting THING to NOTHING. isn't better?! )

3. And even simpler :

Just using `Complement` :

```
Complement[{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79}, {2, 4, 56}]
```

**BE CAUTIONED !! Using each one of the mentioned ways WILL NOT take the same (asymptotically) time to evaluate.**

Just for representation , we could compare these two ways in list with length of 10^6 :

For the first route :

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  Table[DeleteCases[Range[10^6], 
     a_?(MemberQ[RandomInteger[10^6, 100], #] &)];, 5]] // First
```

which gives me `124.474` (means 124 seconds).

And for the second way:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  Table[Range[10^6] /. 
     a_ /; MemberQ[RandomInteger[10^6, 100], a] -> Nothing;, 
   5]] // First
```

Which gives me `124.8` (means 124 seconds).

While the third way :

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  Table[Complement[Range[10^6], RandomInteger[10^6, 100]];, 
   5]] // First
```

just take `0.15` (means 0.15 seconds) !!

Compare those : *124 sec, 124 sec , 0.15 sec*

So the best way is the **third** way especially for larger `List`s ! :)

Comment: Complement is not guaranteed to retain the order, e.g., `Complement[{4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 3}]` returns `{2,4}`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79};

d = {2, 4, 56};
```

Using `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
DeleteElements[list, d]
```

{1, 70, 11, 20, 79}

`Complement`, suggested in the accepted answer, sorts the result:

```
Complement[list, d]
```

{1, 11, 20, 70, 79}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79};

d = {2, 4, 56};
```

Using `Position` and `Delete`:

```
Delete[#, Position[#, Alternatives @@ d]] &@list

(*{1, 70, 11, 20, 79}*)
```

Or using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, And @@ Thread[# != d] & /@ #] &@list

(*{1, 70, 11, 20, 79}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vis = {2, 4, 56} // AssociationMap[True&];

{1, 2, 4, 70, 11, 20, 56, 79} // Select[!KeyExistsQ[#][vis]&]
```

$O(n)$ and keep the order.