# Dropping list elements that are members of other lists

Tags: list-manipulation, subset

I have a set:

$$A=\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3,2\},\{2,1,3\},\{2,3,1\},\{3,1,2\},\{3,2,1\}\}$$

I want to drop elements found in sets B and C from A.

$$B=\{\{1,3,2\},\{2,1,3\}\}$$
$$C=\{\{3,1,2\},\{3,2,1\}\}$$
How can I do this?

---

My attempts:

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}
B = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}}
C = {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}
DeleteCases[A, B]
```

It does not give the desired result
I had to write it like this

```
DeleteCases[A, {1, 3, 2}]
```

I also tried to do it iteratively but it did not work.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is exactly what [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) does

Comment: Please start variable names with lowercase letters. Names starting with uppercase letters are used by the system.

Comment: Here is one method. `In[113]:= 
aA = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 
    1}};
bB = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}};
cC = {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}};
DeleteCases[aA, Apply[Alternatives, Join[bB, cC]]]

Out[116]= {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}}`

Comment: Or wait for version 13.1 and do this. `In[4]:= DeleteElements[aA, Join[bB, cC]]                                        

Out[4]= {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}}`

Comment: One potential (documented) problem with `Complement` is that the output is sorted. See [Complement\[\] changes order of elements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59365/106) and [How to Delete Elements from List1 appearing in List2?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/106) and  [UnsortedComplement](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/UnsortedComplement/), a resource function that "Delete the elements of some lists from a list x without changing either the order of x or the multiplicities of its elements" by George Beck

Comment: Compare `DeleteCases[new, Alternatives@@Join[b,c]]` with `Complement[new, b,c]`, where `new=Reverse@a`

Answer (score 6):

This is the exact use case for [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}};
b = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}};
c = {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}};

Complement[a, b, c]

(* Out: {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}} *)
```

As an aside, do not use variable names that start with capital letters because those have customarily been reserved for built in functions. In particular, avoid using single-letter uppercase variable names like `A`, `B`, [`C`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html?q=C) (used as a constant in equation solving), [`I`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/I.html) (the imaginary unit), [`E`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html) (the base of natural logarithms), `K`, and more: many have built-in meaning which can lead to odd behavior and hard-to-trace bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Using **DeleteCases**:

This will delete any `x` such that `x` is a member of either `b` or `c`.

```
DeleteCases[a, x_ /; MemberQ[b, x] || MemberQ[c, x]]
```

---

Using **Complement**:

```
Complement[Complement[a, b], c]
```

or better still:

```
Fold[Complement, a, {b, c}]
```

---

Result:

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}}

Comment: ... or better still: `Complement[a, b, c]`. There is no need to apply the function twice, or to fold it over the input.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility to achieve this is to join all sets to be replaced and then successively delete them (note also, do not use capitalized variable names, they are reserved for the system):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}};
b = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}};
c = {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}};
```

We set tmp to a and then delete the subsets:

```
tmp = a;
Scan[(tmp = DeleteCases[tmp, #]) &, Join[b, c], 1];
tmp

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}} *)
```