# how to substract two tuples selections

Tags: filtering

i have two tuples select done with modulo on a range {-1,1} :

```
Select[Tuples[Range[-1, 1], 3], Mod[Total[#], 1] == 0 &]
```

and

```
Select[Tuples[Range[-1, 1], 3], Mod[Total[#], 2] == 0 &]
```

these generates coordinates for centers of spheres .

I am trying to filter the first select (mod 1) to remove the result of the second select (mod 2) from it in order to remove the coordinates that match in the two select from the final result.

How can it be achieved ?

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/44141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f = Select[Tuples[Range[-1, 1], 3], Mod[Total[#], 1] == 0 &]
g = Select[Tuples[Range[-1, 1], 3], Mod[Total[#], 2] == 0 &]
```

If we want to delete `g` from `f`:

```
DeleteCases[f, Alternatives @@ g]

Fold[Cases[#1, Except@#2] &,f,g]
```

Comment: `Complement[f, g]` is way more compact.

Comment: @J.M. Absolutely!