# What is the fastest way to delete multiple entries from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

Mathematica allows Deleting multiple objects from a list given their position. However, if I don't know their positions (finding their positions in the list is too costly if the list is long), how can I directly delete multiple objects from a List in an efficient manner (based on their value)?

Comment: `DeleteCases` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the deleted values to `Nothing` with a `Dispatch` rule list.

```
someList = RandomInteger[{1, 5000}, 50000];
someDelList = RandomInteger[{1, 500}, 500];
someDelRules = Dispatch[Map[# -> Nothing &, someDelList]];
```

It can compare favorably timing wise with the naive overhead of sweeping through to find positions, then dropping those positions with Delete.

```
RepeatedTiming[someNewList1 = someList /. someDelRules;]
```

yields

> {0.012, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[
 someNewList2 = 
   Delete[someList, 
    Flatten[Position[someList, #] & /@ someDelList, 1]];]
```

yields

> {1.72, Null}

With `someNewList2 === someNewList1` $\mapsto$ `True` and
`Length[someNewList]`$\mapsto$ 46862 .

Can also compare with a naive `DeleteCases`:

```
RepeatedTiming[
  someNewList3 = 
   DeleteCases[someList, (x_ /; !FreeQ[someDelList, x])];]
```

yielding:

> {0.815, Null}

With also `someNewList3 === someNewList1`$\mapsto$`True`.

### Update

`Alternatives` is the [magic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1291/51526) for `DeleteCases`.

```
  RepeatedTiming[
     someNewList4 = 
     DeleteCases[someList, Alternatives[someList]];]
```

yields

> (.0053, Null)

Documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html).