# Is there an easy way to delete a list of cases from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm doing some game simulation of the game [shut the box](https://www.mastersofgames.com/rules/shut-box-rules.htm) for [538's weekly riddle](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/can-you-find-the-perfect-poker-hand-can-you-shut-this-infernal-box/). I'm constructing simulations of the game using a list of all possible moves, which I achieved using this code:

```
CleanList[list_] := DeleteDuplicates[list];
RemoveLists[list_, x_] := Select[list, Total@# == x &]
Moves[x_] := RemoveLists[CleanList /@ IntegerPartitions[x], x]
AllPossibleMoves = {}; For[i = 1, i <= 9, i++, AppendTo[AllPossibleMoves, Moves[i]]];
```

Which gives us the list:

```
AllPossibleMoves = {{{1}},{{2}},{{3},{2,1}},{{4},{3,1}},{{5},{4,1},{3,2}},{{6},{5,1},{4,2},{3,2,1}},{{7},{6,1},{5,2},{4,3},{4,2,1}},{{8},{7,1},{6,2},{5,3},{5,2,1},{4,3,1}},{{9},{8,1},{7,2},{6,3},{6,2,1},{5,4},{5,3,1},{4,3,2}}}
```

From there, I took the initial game setup (`InitialGameState=Range[9]`) and used the [code I got from this wonderful site yesterday](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171078/is-there-a-simple-way-to-perform-the-opposite-of-intersection-on-two-lists) to compute all the possible states after the first move:

```
MakeMove[list1_,list2_]:=Complement[Union[list1,list2],Intersection[list1,list2]];
For[i=1,i<=Length[AllPossibleMoves],i++, AppendTo[Turn2States, For[j=1,j<=Length[AllPossibleMoves[[i]]],j++,AppendTo[Turn2States,MakeMove[InitialGameState,AllPossibleMoves[[i,j]]]]]]]
```

Then I deleted the Nulls, to clean up the list (`Turn2States = DeleteCases[Turn2States, Null]`).

From here though, I don't know how to proceed. I was going to use `MakeMove` with `AllPossibleMoves` and `Turn2States`. Unfortunately, using `MakeMove` like `MakeMove[{1,2,3},{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}]` gives `{1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` . Which just gets me going in circles because it adds the 1 back in. Is there a simple way to delete a list of numbers from another list like so:

```
Operation[{1,3,4,5,7},{1,2,3,4,5,6}] = {2,6}
```

**Edit:** I found [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153703/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-delete-multiple-entries-from-a-list) on a similar question but it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried doing

```
list = DeleteCases[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, Alternatives[{1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9}]];
```

But that gives: `list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` instead of `list = {3}`

Comment: `Operation[a_,b_]:=Complement[b,a]`?

Comment: The syntax for `Alternatives` should be `Alternatives @@ {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9}` or simply `Alternatives[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9]`.