# How to use Intersection[] but keep the original list order?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, sorting

I want to keep the original order of l1:

```
l1 = {"qwe", "abc", "abb", "aba", "ddd"};
l2 = {"abc", "abd", "aba", "qwe"};
Intersection[l1, l2]
```

Output: {"aba", "abc", "qwe"}

Expected output: {"qwe", "abc", "aba"}

Comment: Related [How to Delete Elements from List1 appearing in List2?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/5379)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To keep the original order, use Cases[] with Alternatives:

```
l1 = {"qwe", "abc", "abb", "aba", "ddd"};
l2 = {"abc", "abd", "aba", "qwe"};
Cases[l1, Apply[Alternatives, l2]]
```

Output: {"qwe", "abc", "aba"}

Use AbsoluteTiming to benchmark this solution - processing time is comparable to Intersection[].

If this helps you, remember to up-vote. :)

**AbsoluteTiming[] benchmarks:** (see dataset creation instructions below)

```
Intersection[l1, l2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.008827, Null}

```
Cases[l1, Apply[Alternatives, l2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.003104, Null}

```
Select[l1, MemberQ[l2, #] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{2.24958, Null}

```
Map[If[MemberQ[l2, #], #, Nothing] &, l1]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{2.22717, Null}

```
Reap[If[MemberQ[l2, #], Sow[#]] & /@ l1][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{2.21488, Null}

```
PositionIndex[Join[l1, l2]] // Select[Length[#] > 1 &] // 
    Values[#, First] & // Part[Join[l1, l2], #] &; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.033102, Null}

```
With[{L = Join[l1, l2]}, 
   Part[L, Values[Select[PositionIndex@L, Length@# > 1 &]][[All, 
      1]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.032718, Null}

```
CreateDataStructure["OrderedHashSet", l1]["Intersection", l2][
   "Elements"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image] in Mathematica 12.1

{0.011508, Null}

```
list = Map[StringJoin, Tuples[RandomSample[Alphabet[], 5], 6]];
Print["List length: ", Length[list]]
l1 = RandomSample[list, IntegerPart[Length[list]*0.6]];
l2 = RandomSample[list, IntegerPart[Length[list]*0.6]];
```

List length: 15625

Answer (score 10):

One way to keep the order in `l1` is this:

```
l1 = {"qwe", "abc", "abb", "aba", "ddd"};
l2 = {"abc", "abd", "aba", "qwe"};
Select[l1, MemberQ[l2, #] &]
(* {"qwe", "abc", "aba"} *)
```

Note that the `Select` function has been in
Mathematica since version 1.0. The alternative
`Map[If[MemberQ[l2, #], #, Nothing] &, l1]`
does the same thing. A variant is
`Reap[If[MemberQ[l2, #], Sow[#]] & /@ l1][[2, 1]]`.

Comment: `Select[l1, MemberQ[l2, #] &]` is similar in spirit, but a bit more elegant.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for that helpful comment!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new data structure functionality in M12.1 to do this. For example:

```
l1 = {"qwe", "abc", "abb", "aba", "ddd"};
l2 = {"abc", "abd", "aba", "qwe"};

ds = CreateDataStructure["OrderedHashSet", l1]["Intersection", l2]["Elements"]
```

> {"qwe", "abc", "aba"}

A bit of explanation. `CreateDataStructure["OrderedHashSet", l1]` creates a data structure containing `l1`. Then, giving `"Intersection", l2` as the arguments of the data structure intersects the contents of the data structure with the set `l2`, returning the data structure. Finally, using "Elements" as the argument to the returned data structure gives the remaining elements.

Comment: Ran in 12.1, return the following error: DataStructure::noop: Elements is not a known operation for OrderedHashSet.

Comment: Works beautifully in 12.3 and really interestingly illustrates the use of CreateDataStructure[]. +1

Answer (score 3):

A wonderfully over-engineered solution:

```
l1 = {"qwe", "abc", "abb", "aba", "ddd"};
l2 = {"abc", "abd", "aba", "qwe"};
PositionIndex[Join[l1, l2]] //
   Select[Length[#] > 1 &] //
   Values[#, First] & //
   Part[Join[l1, l2], #] &
```

Comment: A light variation is `With[{L = Join[l1, l2]}, 
 Part[L, Values[Select[PositionIndex@L, Length@# > 1 &]][[All, 1]]]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `DeleteCases`, `Complement` and `Alternatives`:

```
DeleteCases[l1, Alternatives @@ Complement[l1, l2]]

(*{"qwe", "abc", "aba"}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `V 13.1` there is `DeleteElements`

```
l1 = {"qwe", "abc", "abb", "aba", "ddd"};
l2 = {"abc", "abd", "aba", "qwe"};

DeleteElements[l1, Complement[l1, l2]]
```

{"qwe", "abc", "aba"}

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
l1 = {"qwe", "abc", "abb", "aba", "ddd"};
l2 = {"abc", "abd", "aba", "qwe"};

r1 = # -> # & /@ l1
r2 = # -> # & /@ l2

KeyTake[r2, Keys@r1] // Keys
```

{"qwe", "abc", "aba"}