# Unexpected behaviour of Condition with Cases/MatchQ?

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

When using the unsorted version of `Complement` in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1290) I met the following unexpected result,

```
list1 = {a -> b /; c, a -> b, a};
Cases[list1, Alternatives @@ list1]

Out[]={a -> b, a}
```

Similarly for `MatchQ`,

```
MatchQ[Condition[a, b], Condition[a, b]]

Out[]=False

ClearAll@f;
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
MatchQ[f[x, y], f[x, y]]

Out[]=True
```

and I need to inactivate `Condition` in expressions.

How to understand this behaviour?

Comment: `MatchQ[f[x, y], f[x, y]]` returns `True` whether or not `f` has the attribute `HoldAll`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Condition[a, b]` is pattern that matches `a` provided `b` is `True`. But `Condition[a, b]` (the first argument to `MatchQ`) does not match `a` nor is `b` true.

`Verbatim` is designed for expressions which are usually interpreted as patterns.

```
MatchQ[Condition[a, b], Verbatim[Condition][a, b]]
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: The same applies to `list1`. `a -> b /; c` matches `Rule[a, b]`, provided `c` is `True`. It doesn't really matter whether one puts the condition inside or out in this case, i.e., `Rule[a, b /; c]` or `Rule[a, b] /; c`.

Comment: Thx! I never used Verbatim before. Does this function have other usages besides matching rules with rules?

Comment: @Lilyric `Verbatim` can be wrapped around anything that you want to match as literal code and not to function as a pattern. E.g. `a_ -> b /. Verbatim[a_] :> x` results in `x -> b`, whereas `a_ -> b /. a_ :> x` results in `x`. Sometimes you see it used where `HoldPattern` would be better expressive of the intent. For instance, the following are effectively equivalent: `Verbatim[Integrate][f_, x_]`,
`HoldPattern[Integrate][f_, x_]`,
`HoldPattern[Integrate[f_, x_]]`. The difference is what gets evaluated, but what is evaluated does not change; so they end up matching the same things.

Comment: I see, thx! Does `Verbatim` have a partner like `Hold` vs. `ReleaseHold`, `Inactivate` vs. `Activate`? I read the documentation but hasn't found one.

Comment: @Lilyric No, I don't think so.  Usually `Verbatim` is on the pattern-matching side of a rule and does not propagate through a computation. `Hold` and `Inactive` are used to stop an expression from evaluation until it reaches a certain step in a computation, at which point `ReleaseHold` or `Activate` is needed. `HoldPattern` is similar to `Verbatim` in this respect. While `ReleaseHold` works on it, I don't recall ever doing that. If you need a way to "release" `Verbatim`, try something like `expr /. Verbatim[Verbatim][h_] :> h`.

Answer (score 4):

To start with, `Condition` has semantic meaning in Cases/MatchQ:

```
With[
  {b = True},
  Cases[{Condition[a, b], a}, Condition[a, b]]]
(* {a} *)
```

That explains why `MatchQ[Condition[a, b], Condition[a, b]]` returns `False`. Just for grins, let's try this:

```
MatchQ[3, 3 /; False]
(* False *)
```

Now let's work through your first example. A couple of variables to hold our expressions:

```
list1 = {a -> b /; c, a -> b, a};
alts = Alternatives @@ list1;
```

Start with something simpler:

```
Cases[list1, alts[[1]]]
(* {b /; c} *)
```

What happened? Well, in `Cases` you can give a rule to actually replace the value that matched. `alts[[1]]` is `a -> b /; c`, so we matched on `a` and replaced it with `b/;c`. Similarly:

```
Cases[list1, alts[[2]]]
(* {b} *)
```

Next, something a bit more complicated:

```
Cases[list1, alts[[2 ;; 2]]]
(* {a -> b} *)
```

This time we matched against an `Alternatives`, not a `Rule`, so we don't do replacement. However, we did find an exact match.

Okay, moving on again:

```
Cases[list1, alts[[1 ;; 1]]]
(* {} *)
```

No matches! We're matching against `Alternatives`, not `Rule`, so we should be looking at the whole `a -> b /; c` expression. The problem is that the `Condition` still comes into play. Rather than try to explain directly, it's easier to find something that **does** match:

```
Cases[{a -> b}, Alternatives[a -> b /; True]]
(* {a -> b} *)

MatchQ[a -> b, a -> b /; True]
(* True *)
```

We're matching the `b` part as long as the `Condition[b, True]` is satisfied, which it is by definition. The condition of `Condition[b, c]` is not satisfied, so we're not matching the `b`.

`Verbatim` is used in patterns where you want to match exactly--no transformation or interpretation. So, you could try this:

```
Cases[list1, Alternatives @@ Verbatim /@ list1]
(* {a -> b /; c, a -> b, a} *)
```

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation!