# How to delete a word set in a text?

Tags: filtering, text, contexts, text-formatting

I have a setence:

```
text= {Concerning the main ecological question on the complexity-stability relationship, our findings reveal that high species diversities and dynamical stability of growing ecological networks are very constrained under a widespread biochemical warfare between the interacting species. Indeed, the rate in which species abundance decreases as the number of strong allelopathic interactions increases is faster than those predicted by May’s classical analysis};
```

I would like to remove the banal terms of the `text` from an indicated `list` that include a special character showed below

```
list={’s, concerning, the, main, on, our, that, of, are, in, as, is, to, a, by, may, for, be, an, and, other, others, which, not, out};
```

Version 13.1 of Mathematica has the function DeleteElements, which:

```
DeleteElements[text, list];
```

However, earlier versions of Mathematica do not have this tool. How to remove a list of words in a text in old versions of Mathematica?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a problem in the question. I guess `text` should be a List of Strings, not a List of variables named *Concerning* , *the* , *main* etc..

Comment: It is not clear whether your `text` is one string or a list of words. If the former, then `DeleteElements` will not work and you should use [`StringDelete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringDelete.html). If the latter, see [How to Delete Elements from List1 appearing in List2?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/how-to-delete-elements-from-list1-appearing-in-list2).

Answer (score 4):

To eliminate first define the text as wordlist and the "list" as alternatives:

```
text = StringSplit[
   "Concerning the main ecological question on the \
complexity-stability relationship,our findings reveal that high \
species diversities and dynamical stability of growing ecological \
networks are very constrained under a widespread biochemical warfare \
between the interacting species.Indeed,the rate in which species \
abundance decreases as the number of strong allelopathic interactions \
increases is faster than those predicted by May\[CloseCurlyQuote]s \
classical analysis"];

list = Alternatives @@ 
   ToLowerCase[
    StringSplit[
     "\[CloseCurlyQuote]s,concerning,the,main,on,our,that,of,are,in,\
as,is,to,a,by,may,for,be,an,and,other,others,which,not,out", ","]];
```

Now we can use "Cases":

```
Cases[text, s_ /; ! MemberQ[list, ToLowerCase[s]]]

{"ecological", "question", "complexity-stability", \
"relationship,our", "findings", "reveal", "high", "species", \
"diversities", "dynamical", "stability", "growing", "ecological", \
"networks", "very", "constrained", "under", "widespread", \
"biochemical", "warfare", "between", "interacting", \
"species.Indeed,the", "rate", "species", "abundance", "decreases", \
"number", "strong", "allelopathic", "interactions", "increases", \
"faster", "than", "those", "predicted", "May\[CloseCurlyQuote]s", \
"classical", "analysis"}
```

Comment: `ReplaceAll[twords, s_ /; MemberQ[list, ToLowerCase[s]] :> Nothing]` works fine too.